# How to set permanent ACLs on hardware (/dev) devices in systemd?

Tags: linux, permissions, webcam, systemd, acl

I tried to prevent a user from accessing the webcam via [`systemd` ACLs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists), but whatever I set is reset on a new login:

- For regular files, this works just fine, with any access by `userx` to `random_file` returning `Permission denied`:

  ```
  sudo setfacl -m u:userx:--- random_file
  ```
- However, doing the same to the webcam device will change the permissions correctly and prevent `userx` from using the webcam, but after I log out, or switch to `userx` for testing, the permissions are reset:

  ```
  sudo setfacl -m u:userx:--- /dev/video0
  ```

  ```bsh
  # file: dev/video0
  # owner: root
  # group: video
  user::rw-
  user:userx:rw-
  group::rw-
  mask::rw-
  other::---
  ```

Why is this and is there a way to make ACLs on `/dev/video*` permanent?

Comment: I've mostly written an answer, but first, _why_ do you need to make this specific change? Do you want to disable a webcam in general, or something else?

Comment: I would like to disable a webcam for a specific user for good, but not "in general" as in "system wide".

Comment: I'm about 99% sure you will need to write a udev rule to make this happen (basically, the /dev/ entry doesn't exist until after the hardware is enumerated, and I bet you could make this happen by unplugging the webcam as well), but I am not well versed on how to do that.